# Angular 10:how to compare two arrays

Tags: javascript, angular

I have two arrays, one with colors, and one with categories.

```js
"colors": [
        {
          "buttonId": "color-cinder-spark-red",
          "filmCategory": 1,
          "name": "cinder spark red",
          "previewImg": "assets/filmPreviewImg/gloss-cinder-spark-red.png",
          "default": true
        },
        {
          "buttonId": "color-gloss-red-metallic",
          "filmCategory": 2,
          "name": "red metallic",
          "previewImg": "assets/filmPreviewImg/gloss-red-metallic.png"
        },
        {
          "buttonId": "color-dragon-red",
          "filmCategory": 3,
          "name": "dragon red",
          "previewImg": "assets/filmPreviewImg/gloss-dragon-red.png"
        },...
```

The array is very large.

Here is categories:

```js
"types": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Gloss",
          "type": "gloss"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Matte",
          "type": "matte",
          "default": true
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Satin",
          "type": "satin"
        },...
```

In an array of colors, the category is displayed as id. I need to compare the id of the selected color with the category, and then get the name of the category. Here I will get the category id of the selected color

```
  filmTypes = filmTypes.types;
  filmColors = filmColors.colors;

  currentColor: any;
 
  modalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService,
              private _productService: ProductService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const defaultColor = this.filmColors.find((c) => c.default);
    this.selectColor(defaultColor);  
       
    this._productService.currentFilmColor$.subscribe((color: any) => {      
      this.currentColor = color.filmCategory;          
      console.log('color2',this.currentColor);            
    });    
  }
```

How can I compare this id in another array and get the category name?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#find`.

```
const { name } = filmTypes.find(({ id }) => id === this.currentColor);
```